# Macro to copy paste multiple excel ranges in PPT

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have finally been able to create this macro, which copying data from a specific range in excel and pasting it into an existing PPT.

Now I want to repeat this action for multiple slides, but instead of copy pasting this macro, again and again, is there any shorter code where I just change the range, destination slide, positioning and it creates the complete set.

Here is the existing code which is working fine:

```
'Macro1
Sub excelrangetopowerpoint_month()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim powerpointapp As Object
    Dim mypresentation As Object
    Dim destinationPPT As String
    Dim myshape As Object
    Dim myslide As Object

    Set rng = Worksheets("objectives").Range("m1")

    On Error Resume Next

    Set powerpointapp = CreateObject("powerpoint.application")
    destinationPPT = ("C:\Users\OLX-Admin\Dropbox (Corporate Finance)\Naspers Monthly Reporting\Prep for call\From teams\FY2019\OLX Group Monthly Report_Sep'18_Macro.pptx")
    powerpointapp.Presentations.Open (destinationPPT)

    On Error GoTo 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set mypresentation = powerpointapp.ActivePresentation
    Set myslide = mypresentation.Slides(1)

    rng.Copy

    myslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2 '2 = enhanced metafile
    Set myshape = myslide.Shapes(myslide.Shapes.Count)

    myshape.Left = 278
    myshape.Top = 175

    powerpointapp.Visible = True
    powerpointapp.Activate

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with another procedure like below. So you only have to duplicate one line for every copy to a slide.

Also note that your error handling was silent. That's a bad idea, because if an error occurs you just ignore it and you will never notice. Also the following code would not work properly. I changed that too.

```
Sub excelrangetopowerpoint_month()
    Dim powerpointapp As Object
    Set powerpointapp = CreateObject("powerpoint.application")

    Dim destinationPPT As String
    destinationPPT = ("C:\Users\OLX-Admin\Dropbox (Corporate Finance)\Naspers Monthly Reporting\Prep for call\From teams\FY2019\OLX Group Monthly Report_Sep'18_Macro.pptx")

    On Error GoTo ERR_PPOPEN
    Dim mypresentation As Object
    Set mypresentation = powerpointapp.Presentations.Open(destinationPPT)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    PasteToSlide mypresentation.Slides(1), Worksheets("objectives").Range("m1")
    'duplicate this line for all slides/ranges
    'PasteToSlide mypresentation.Slides(2), Worksheets("objectives").Range("m2")

    powerpointapp.Visible = True
    powerpointapp.Activate

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

ERR_PPOPEN:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'don't forget to turn it on!
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Failed to open " & destinationPPT, vbCritical
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub PasteToSlide(mySlide As Object, rng As Range)
    rng.Copy
    mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2 '2 = enhanced metafile

    Dim myShape As Object
    Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

    myShape.Left = 278
    myShape.Top = 175
End Sub
```